# How to get tableview header to adjust font to fit width

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

I am using the following line of code to adjust my tableview header font.
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];

How can I adjust this font to fit width? The line below does not work?
    [UILabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several solutions to this

1. Use Auto-Resizing, which will take some time if you are  not familiar with
2. Use below method on NSString object to find the size of resultant string with specified size and find the appropriate font size, like

[@"CheckString" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]] ;

Comment: I just found this and it \seems to work for adjusting the header to adjust the font to fit:         [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
Now trying to center the text?